# Variable doesn't update in global scope when using setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that will return a variable that I can use inside another function. Another function should use time comparison between current time and some other selected time. I figured I could make time variable accessible in global scope by using return and property and update it by using `setInterval()`.

Unfortunately when I "import" the variable to another function, the time variable isn't updated.

Why doesn't
`console.log('time cool outside' + obj.debug );` 
return the same value as `console.log('time cool inside' + timeCool);`?

```
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
  }

function timeFunction() {
  let today = new Date();
  let hours = today.getHours();
  let minutes = today.getMinutes();
  minutes = checkTime(minutes);
  hours = checkTime(hours);
  let stringHours = hours.toString();
  let stringMinutes = minutes.toString();
  time = stringHours + stringMinutes;
  let timeCool = parseInt(time);
  console.log('time cool inside' + timeCool);
  return {
    debug: timeCool,
  };

}
let obj = timeFunction();
setInterval(timeFunction, 5000);
function a() {console.log('time cool outside' + obj.debug );}
setInterval(a, 5000);
```

Comment: could you share the faulty output that you get?

Comment: yes. The  'time outside' isn't updated

2
choices.js:21 time cool inside1414
choices.js:29 time cool outside1414
choices.js:21 time cool inside1415
choices.js:29 time cool outside1414
choices.js:21 time cool inside1415
choices.js:29 time cool outside1414
choices.js:21 time cool inside1415

Comment: obj is created at `let obj = timeFunction();` after this it is never updated and that's what you're printing, so it looks like it's never being updated

Answer (score 4):

in the lines

```
let obj = timeFunction();
setInterval(timeFunction, 5000);
```

you create a global object `obj` and set it to the output of `timeFunction`. Then with `setInterval` you call `timeFunction` periodically, but never set `obj` to its output. Thus, when `a` accesses `obj` it never changes

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what you are doing here:

```
let obj = timeFunction();
```

Here you call the `timeFunction` and store it's result into `obj`.

```
setInterval(timeFunction, 5000);
```

Here you call `timeFunction` every 5 seconds. The return value is dismissed.

```
function a() {console.log('time cool outside' + obj.debug );}
```

Here you have a new function that references the `obj` variable defined before. `obj` is the return value of the first call to `timeFunction` and has never been changed, so it will always have the same value, no matter how often you call any of those two functions.

If you want to update `obj` you need to do so inside `timeFunction` or continue to set it to the return value of `timeFunction`.

Comment: I like the way you explain it, I guess that's more than enough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping. Indeed I didn't notice that I didn't update "obj" variable.

After implementing this:

```
let obj;
function objUpdate() {
obj = timeFunction();
}
setInterval(objUpdate, 1000);
```

Everything looks like I wanted :)
Thank you all!